# PHP referencing to last inserted element in array

Tags: php

Is there a way in php to find out exactly where my element was inserted into an array i.e. at which postion it was inserted into the array. For like the following code I need to insert an element at any position of the array then insert a sub element at the second diimenson of that array

```
$myarray=array();
$myarray[]=$someelementdefinedbefore;
$myarray[][2]=$second element related to some element defined before;
```

i.e. i need the two elements mentioned above to be clubbed together so i can later access them both via a single array search

Any idea how I could make this work. I mean I know I could use array search for this but I wanted to know if there was more efficient solution available?

Comment: [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) ?

Comment: $myarray=array();
$myarray[]=$someelementdefinedbefore;
$myarray[][2]=$second element of same array;

why you making it a two dimesional array??

Comment: @rohitarora sorry i hadnt expained the question clearly enough, kindly read the edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myarray=array();
$myarray[]=$someelementdefinedbefore; // This will be the last element as it is appended.

$myArrayLastElement = count($myarray)-1; // get the key of the last element.
// append your second element to this array.
$myarray[$myArrayLastElement][2]=$second element
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to add the second one as two dimensional array.

```
$myarray=array();
$myarray[]=$someelementdefinedbefore;
$myarray[]=$second element of same array;
```

here `$myarray[0]` will give you first value of the array, 
and `$myarray[1]` will give you second value of the array

Comment: sorry i hadnt expained the question clearly enough, kindly read the edited question